# How to display data value from web sql

Tags: javascript, html, web-sql

I'm trying to insert current date and time into web-sql,
then I want to display that current date and time in list page. How?

I'm using `document.getElementById('tbh_tgl').value=(today+now), tambah_tgl();` to enter the date and time

Setting format date and time

```
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
var hh = today.getHours();
var mn = today.getMinutes();
if(dd<10) {
    dd='0'+dd
} 

if(mm<10) {
    mm='0'+mm
} 
if(hh<10) {
    hh='0'+hh
}
if(mn<10) {
    mn='0'+mn
}
today = dd+'-'+mm+'-'+yyyy;
var now = ' '+hh+':'+mn;
```

Function for insert data

```
function tambah_tgl(){
    if(mydb){
         var tgl = document.getElementById('tbh_tgl').value;
            mydb.transaction(function (t) {
                t.executeSql("INSERT INTO history (tanggal) VALUES (?)", [tgl]);
            });
    } 
    else 
    {
        alert("database not found, browser not support web sql!");
    }
}
```

I want to display data in here (list page):

```html
<li class="list-item">
 <div class="list-item__center">
   <p id="tbh_tgl"></p>
 </div>
</li>
```

The data doesn't show up here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text inside a `<p>` element is not in `element.value` but `element.textContent`.

`document.getElementById('tbh_tgl').textContent = (today+now)`

`var tgl = document.getElementById('tbh_tgl').textContent`

Comment: Whenever you come across a problem like this, you should go into devtools and get the DOM element into the console, then see what properties are on it and which one has what you need. That's exactly what I did.